# ¿Cómo eliminar procesos de Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, entity-framework, code-first

Tengo el siguiente código que me gustaria guardar en Excel. El problema es que, al ejecutarlo, me genera muchos procesos muertos en el administrador de tareas y no tengo manera de eliminarlos.

```
private void BtnGUARDAR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Hoja1"];            
        worksheet.Name = cmbTRANSPORTISTA.SelectedValue.ToString();
        var Excel = new SaveFileDialog();
        DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;
        Excel.FileName = "Distribución";
        Excel.DefaultExt = "xlsx";
        if (Excel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(Excel.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        }
        System.GC.Collect();
    }
```

Termine utilizando este pedazo de codigo para eliminar los procesos "Excel" directamente

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] process=System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel");
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in process)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.ProcessName))
    {
        try
        {
            p.Kill();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mira tuve un problema parecido y lo resolví con este código (esta en visual)

```
   Try
    Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process
      For Each proc In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
                If proc.MainWindowTitle.Trim.Length = 0 Then
                    proc.Kill()
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("No es posible elminar los procesos abiertos de Excel ocupados por el sistema. Puede cerrarlos Manualmente desde el Administrador de Tareas, en pestaña procesos, buscando aquellos con nombre EXCEL y cerrandolos individualmente. Se recomienda, antes de llevar a cabo este proceso, no tener plantillas excel, de otros trabajos, abiertas en su sesión.", CType(vbExclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, MsgBoxStyle), "Mensaje del Sistema")
        End Try
```

Por lo que vi en el código no cierras el libro de tareas, quizás por esa razón se te generan tantos procesos excel,
bastaría con workbook.Close() para cerrarlo cuando termines la operacion.

espero que te ayude, saludos.

Comment: Gracias! me fue de mucha utilidad!